# 5-digit Bicycle Odometer available for bike computers?

Tags: bike-computer, long-distance

Are there any bike computers that give you a five-digit odometer for pure cyclists like myself?  If ever, I would pay up to around $25 so as to save money.

Comment: Now, I would say with shipping that the gadget cost up to $20 or so and I know it would be buyable on-line, not my small town where I have a bike shop and a Wal-Mart SuperCenter.

Comment: What is a "pure cyclist" and what does purity have to do with five digits? And what do you mean by paying up to $25 to save money?

Comment: I've only seen up to 4 digits, but keeping track of rollovers every 10,000 miles doesn't seem like much of a burden for most cyclists.

Comment: @Johnny perhaps paint a tally mark on the computer every time it rolls over.

Answer (score 3):

From the bike computers I have owned, Sigma and VDO have had 5-digit odometers. No doubt there are other brands too.

Comment: Good find, the [Sigma Pure 1](http://sigmasport.com/en/produkte/fahrrad-computer/trendline/wired/pure-1/highlights) advertises that it _"can record the Total Distance up to 99,999 KM or MI"_

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a smartphone?  Look for the Strava app which uses http://strava.com/ as a backend to record all your rides.

The number of digits thing becomes irrelevant, and logs which bike did the distance.

You don't need to enter into the competitive side of strava.  You can simply make all your rides private by default, and default to viewing your own times instead of the fastest.

[image: Screenshot of Strava's Gear page. My own work.]
The bike names mean something to me, and very few of them had a "brand"

Comment: Not a fan of strava myself but +1 for the principle. You can certainly have this style of display as you ride on the app I use (ipbike).

Comment: @ChrisH yes I suspect OP is looking for the retro clicker-style odometer that fastens to a fork/hub.  They look cool but they're terrible to line up and calibrate.

Comment: I wondered about those. It could also be a dedicated digital bike computer that the OP wants. Let's see if they come back

Comment: Given that the question opens with "Are there any bike computers", I suspect the OP is looking for a bike computer

Comment: @ojs given the lack of clarity in the Q who knows what they're after. My bike computer (and that is what I call it) is an app, and the mechanical speed/distance units are sometimes referred to as computers probably so they show up searching under modern terms.

Comment: @ChrisH I understand you have your personal vocabulary. However, before using terms in communication with other people, I'd recommend at least doing a simple web search to see what others believe a word means.

Comment: @ojs is not a matter of personal vocabulary. That's the term to use on app stores if you want something that's more about the display and data than the social upload stuff. As for the mechanical things, I'm reporting on other people's eBay listings etc. that have shown up when I've been looking for something fitting your rather narrow definition. Basically I'm assuming the broadest definitions I've seen.